# replacing namespace - problem with attribute's values that have namespace

Tags: xslt, namespaces, xsi

i'm moving from one namespace to another in a XML and i have been facing problems with xsi:type attributes for typed elements. 
I have been using  next template that easily moves element that have one namespace to other one.

```
   <xsl:template match="ent:*" >
    <xsl:element name="ent:{local-name()}"
        namespace="http://ns3">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates  />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

but i'm not able to update attribute values that belongs to a given name space as xsi:type attribute.

```
   <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
   <ser:getAsByIdResponse xmlns:ser="http://osde.com.ar/services">
   <return xmlns:xsi=".." xmlns:ns3New="http://ns3" xmlns:ns1New="http://ns2"   xsi:type="nsold:aType"/>
   </ser:getAsByIdResponse>

   </soap:Body/>

   </soap:Envelope>
```

In above example, i can't change "nsold:atype" to one like "ns3New:atype" that uses the new name spaces.
Is there any way to do adjust this kind of values?

Comment: So, what is the source XML document and what is the wanted XML document that it must be transformed to? Why should a person who is willing to answer have to guess these? Please, edit your question and provide the missing data.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that `nsold:aType` is the textual value of the attribute; It doesn't have a namespace, it's just text. You need a template that modifies the content of the attribute. You might need to adapt it to your needs, but this should demonstrate how to do this:

```
<xsl:template match="@*[starts-with(.,'nsold:')]">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('ns3New:',substring-after(.,'nsold:'))" />
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

This simply substitutes the content of any attribute with text beginning in 'nsold:' with 'ns3New:etc.' instead.

Comment: The proper name of the value type of an attribute when using XPath 1.0 is "string value" -- not "textual value". As per spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-string-value

Comment: Well, if you're going to split hairs about it, the proper name is `string-value` (note the hyphen), however I was describing the content of the attribute, not naming it's type, so it's not really relevant. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Answer (score 1):

The "correct" way to do this is probably with a schema-aware transformation, which recognizes the xsi:type as being of type attribute(*, xs:QName). You can then do an identity transformation supplemented with

```
<xsl:template match="attribute(*, xs:QName)">
  <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}" 
     select="concat(f:new-prefix(namespace-uri-from-QName(.)), 
                    ':', local-name-from-QName(.))"/>
</xsl:template>
```

where f:new-prefix() is a function that maps the namespace URI of the QName to the prefix to be used in the new document.

However, if xsi:type is your only namespace-sensitive content, then you could just handle it as a special case.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning this means using an XSLT2 processor.